# Is it posible to prevent juputer lab from saving notebooks automatically?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I tend to lunch jupyter lab from different locations, open a new notebook to try out something, etc. Jupyter lab creates a notebook and saves it to the disk by default. As a result, I end up with notebooks that I don't want to keep all over my disk drive. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You might find it quickest to use an ephemeral docker container:

```
docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 \
           -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes \
           -e JUPYTER_TOKEN=docker \
           --name jupyter \
           -d jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
```

Comment: This is like trying to cut a cake with a sword.

Comment: Even more ephemeral is to use sessions launched via MyBinder.org right in your browser. You don't need docker locally as it is handled behind the scenes. You can upload notebooks from your local computer or pull or clone or fetch them from other online resources. You can customize the environment if you need to. It's in your browser & nothing is local. After 10 minutes of inactivity the connection will timeout & you have nothing to clean up. A lot of developers use it to offer ways to test things. Look for `launch binder` badges in repos. Example: https://github.com/CermakM/jupyter-datatables

Comment: Not to mention free notebooks from Google Collab https://colab.research.google.com/